# Limit of sum with parameter

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} \frac {1} {k+n} = \ln 2$$

I'm supposed to find the limit and get the right part as an answer. I don't know what to do with it. Could someone explain?

Comment: I knnow this has been asked before. Can't find it, though.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Think of Riemann sums and note that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}\frac{1}{n}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Write it as $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\frac{k}{n}+1}$$

and look it as Riemann sums for the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x+1}dx$$

Answer (score 3):

Let me give another method without using the Riemann sum.

We use the asymptotic expansion
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\log n+\gamma+o(1)$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+n}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\log(2n)-\log(n)+o(1)=\log 2+o(1)$$
and we deduce the desired result.

Comment: +1 , though the "we know that" phrase may be far from true for someone asking such a basic question.

Comment: You're right and thanks for the comment.